# QThread Destroyed while thread is still running

Tags: python, pyside, zeromq, pyside6

I am trying to run ZeroMQ in a QThread. What I do is when a message arrives I emit the msg_received signal. In the App class the show_my_window method is connected to it so it will display a simple dialog.

The problem is as soon as I close that dialog, I get the following

```
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Here is my code:

```
class ZMQThread(QThread):
    msg_received = Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(ZMQThread, self).__init__()
        self.context = zmq.Context()
        self.socket = self.context.socket(zmq.REP)
        self.socket.bind("tcp://*:3344")

    def run(self):
        while True:
            message = self.socket.recv()
            self.msg_received.emit()
            
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MyDialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.ButtonOK.clicked.connect(self.ok)

    def ok(self):
        self.accept()
  
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.qtapp = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
        self.my_window = MyWindow()
        self.zmq_thread = ZMQThread()
        self.zmq_thread.msg_received.connect(self.show_my_window)
        self.zmq_thread.start()

    def show_my_window(self):
        self.my_window.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_gui = App()
    sys.exit(my_gui.qtapp.exec())
```

I don't have a main window here, wondering if that could be a problem? I don't want a main window, this app will run on the tray but first I want to implement this part. I have checked some very similar questions but after checking those solutions they did not work.
What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Qt ends the eventloop when the last open window is closed, and when the eventloop ends, the QThread does not close correctly. The solution is to disable this feature using the [`quitOnLastWindowClosed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop) property:

```py
self.qtapp = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
self.qtapp.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, no event loop has been made because the OP has not [called `exec()` in `run()`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QThread.html#PySide6.QtCore.PySide6.QtCore.QThread.exec).  `run()` would implicitly end execution of the thread [if returning from it](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QThread.html#PySide6.QtCore.PySide6.QtCore.QThread.run), but the OP has an infinite `while True` loop here. Are you speaking of the "main event loop"?